# Consulta SQL retornar valor zerado onde o COUNT encontrar nulo

Tags: mysql, sql, null, count

Olá,
Tenho uma tabela de projetos que nela contém status, responsável e outras colunas.
Estou fazendo a seguinte consulta,

```
  SELECT status,COUNT(status) AS Total 
  FROM projetos 
  WHERE responsavel='Teste' 
  GROUP BY status ORDER BY status;
```

Então retorna apenas os status que aquele `responsavel` tem e eu precisaria que retornasse todos os status porém com o `COUNT(status)` com o valor zerado.

Desta forma a tabela vem desta maneira:

```
+-----------+-------+
| status    | total |
+-----------+-------+
| Cancelado |     1 |
+-----------+-------+
```

E Preciso que venha da seguinte:

```
+-------------+-------+
| status      | total |
+-------------+-------+
| Cancelado   |     1 |
| Finalizado  |     0 |
| Em processo |     0 |
| Parado      |     0 |
| Atrasado    |     0 |
+-------------+-------+
```

O responsável chamado teste tem apenas um projeto no qual o status está como Cancelado.

Comment: A query com LEFT OUTER JOIN faz exatamente o que deseja.

Comment: Mas é apenas uma única tabela que tenho, como ficaria ?

Comment: Então como seu SGBD sabe quais são todos os status possíveis? Ou esta lista existe apenas em sua cabeça?

Comment: É relativo, um usuário pode vir e cadastrar um projeto com um status qualquer que ele desejar, mas a principio são esses do exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Tente a função coalesce que serve exatamente para isso:

```
COALESCE(COUNT(status), 0) AS Total
```

================

Se você tiver uma tabela de status possíveis então utilize um `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT tabela_de_status.status, COALESCE(COUNT(projetos.status), 0) AS Total 
  FROM tabela_de_status LEFT OUTER JOIN ON (tabela_de_status. status = projetos.status)
  WHERE responsavel='$Nome_de_Algum_responsavel' 
  GROUP BY tabela_de_status.status ORDER BY tabela_de_status.status;
```

===============================

Para considerar todos os status existentes na tabela projetos:

```
SELECT tabela_de_status.status, COALESCE(COUNT(projetos.status), 0) AS Total 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT status FROM projetos) AS tabela_de_status LEFT OUTER JOIN ON (tabela_de_status. status = projetos.status)
  WHERE responsavel='$Nome_de_Algum_responsavel' 
  GROUP BY tabela_de_status.status ORDER BY tabela_de_status.status;
```

Mas eu diria que seu banco de dados não está bem estruturado.

Comment: SELECT status,COALESCE(COUNT(status),0) AS total FROM projetos WHERE responsavel='Teste' GROUP BY status ORDER BY status;
Desta forma continua aparecendo apenas o status na qual ele tem um projeto.

Comment: Tente assim : COALESCE(NULLIF(COUNT(status),0,0))

Comment: Você quer dizer que existem valores de status que não existem em sua tabela projetos?

Comment: Na minha tabela tem vários status: Finalizado,Em processo, Atrasado,etc. 
Porém tenho que ter uma consulta que determinado responsável quando não tiver projeto em algum status apareça com o valor zerado.

Edvaldo deu o seguinte erro: ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'NULLIF'

Comment: Desculpe, achei que fosse SQL Server ...

Comment: Estou usando o mysql no XAMPP, alguma outra idéia ?